# How to inject files in special place of file using gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I am going to inject some js and css files into `index.html`, I create the array of paths to files :

```
var paths = {
   js: [
      'a.js',
      '/b/b.js',
      '/c/d/d.js
   ],
   css: [
      'a/a.css',
      'b/b/b.css'
   ]
}
```

in my `index.html` file :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>INDEX</title>
     <!-- inject:css -->
     <!-- endinject -->
 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- inject:js -->
 <!-- endinject -->

 <h1>Hello Index</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and my gulp task is :

```
 gulp.task('index', function () {
   var target = gulp.src('./index.html');

   var sources = gulp.src([paths.js, paths.css], {read: false});

   return target.pipe(inject(sources))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
 });
```

How can I place these files in `index.html`?

Comment: My guess is that since paths.js and paths.css are both arrays and that you use gulp.src([paths.js, paths.css], ...) that that is an invalid glob and hence the error statement.  Do those files actually exist?

Comment: yes, the files exist, but how can i fix the problem?? and if i have three or more inject parts in `index.html` file, how can i handle it? @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gulp-inject` package

```
inject = require('gulp-inject')
```

Gulp task will be like this

```
gulp.task('TASK_NAME', function() {
  var target = gulp.src('./RAW.html');
  return target
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src([...]), {
      read: false
    }), {
      name: 'NAME_IN_HTML'
    }));
});
```

And in `RAW.html` insert this in place:

```
<!-- inject:NAME_IN_HTML -->
<!-- endinject -->
```